# ajax post multiple li elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I've got two sortable lists. I want to send all ids from one list to a php script via ajax. This list is dynamic and the quantity of ids will change. I simply want to gather all ids there and send them out.

Here's what I've got so far, which somewhat works - the item_id var only grabs the first, I want them all - doesn't matter if its all in one string separated by comma/space (whatever), or a new key=>value for each... whichever is easiest.

'roomID' is the unique identifier for the UL/Dialog - which works fine.

```
$( 'div.edit-dialog-'+roomID ).dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 550,
            modal: true,
            position:['middle','middle'],
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Save: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            room_id: roomID,
                            item_id: $("#sortable1-"+roomID+" li").attr("id")
                        },
                        url: "index.php?controller=AdminRegion&action=test",
                        success: function (res) {
                            $("#content").html(res);
                            $("#tabs").tabs();
                        }
                    });
                }

            },
                close: function() {
                    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                }
        });
```

Result:

```
array(2) { ["room_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["item_id"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

I think its a matter of syntax, just don't know how. My second guess would be a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#sortable1-"+roomID+" li")` has all `<li />` elements so you will have to iterate over them to get the id of each of the elements.

If a comma separated list is good enough, you can get this list with

```
$("#sortable1-"+roomID+" li").map(function() {
    return this.id
}).get().join()
```

With that said, your save method could be rewritten as

```
Save: function() {
    var item_ids = $("#sortable1-"+roomID+" li").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            room_id: roomID,
            item_ids: item_ids
        },
        url: "index.php?controller=AdminRegion&action=test",
        success: function (res) {
            $("#content").html(res);
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Guess it was sliiightly more complex then I thought. :) Thanks, Andreas.